Unpack Solaris .p5p on Linux
I have an installer for Solaris 11 I need to unpack, but I don't currently have access to a Solaris 11 box.  We're working on that, but since I don't actually need to install and run what's in the .p5p file, I just want to extract some files, I don't want to wait to bring up a questionable Solaris server to get at it.
The 'file' command says that the p5p file is a "POSIX tar file", and I am able to use tar xf on it to unpack some stuff, but I just end up with a bunch of files with names that are clearly some kind of hash.  (Like: 00/00142df8c...) 'file' says those appear to be gzipped, but I'm guessing that even if I un-gzipped them, they would need to be recombined in some useful way.
So, if there any way I can get this thing unpacked on Linux and get the files I want?
